# How do I remove icon from the launchpad if I already moved app to trash

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, launchpad

So, I had an app, and removed it (moved to trash)

Now, I can see its icon in launchpad (when I click it says "You can't open the application "Name" because it is in the trash.). With only button OK.

How do I remove it from Launchpad completely?

Comment: Several possible solutions in this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/372736/uninstalled-program-icon-stuck-on-launchpad-in-mac-os-x-lion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restored it from trash and removed again and icon disappeared

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, consider marking it as correct, even if the answer is yours.

Comment: @zerohedge, sure but it's impossible to mark own solution in 2 days

Answer (score 2):

Emptying the trash would have worked as well. 
Launchpad shoes all apps it finds via spotlight, not just those who are in the Applications folder.